# Word Processor for iPad with odt or doc compatability

Tags: ios, offline, cloud-service, ipad-app, word-processor

I am looking for a word processor running on iPad for a student to use for taking notes and working on assignments in class.  It will complement an OpenOffice installation running at home so document compatibility and ease of file transfers is a strong consideration.

**Requirements:**

1. Support read/write of either [.odt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) or [.doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.doc#Microsoft_Word_Binary_File_Format) format documents (preferably both)
2. Support read/write of documents on at least one cloud storage service, ie. Google Drive, SkyDrive, Evernote  DropBox etc. (the more the merrier)
3. Ad-Free

**Desirables:**

1. Rich text formatting options (font, size, colour, alignment etc.)
2. Insert/display embedded images
3. Insert/display tables
4. Offline mode for when internet access is unavailable
5. While I would expect to play something for an ad-free product if comparing two options with feature parity I would prefer a low cost solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Office² HD](http://www.bytesquared.com/product/office-hd) for iPad can do all .doc but i'm not to sure about .odt, never seen that extension myself.

In terms of what you wanted:

**Requirements:**

1. As i said i know it does .doc but not sure on .odt but since your question does ask for one *or* the other but preferably boht i would assume you have the means to convert .odt to .doc
2. it's got some upload function but i never used it since i wanted a portable offline word editor, the site does say Full Cloud integration though
3. it's add free but ofcause normally for something to be add free you would need to pay for it

**Desirables:**

1. one of the reasons why i got it as i had created styles for headings....though i'm not 100% on colour though
2. i think i remember being able to add images from your photo gallery on the ipad, not sure about online
3. yes
4. while it does work offline i tend to have a problem where now and again any app i have downloaded will start up then shut down completely until i connect to the app store though this happens with every app
5. it's about $8.00 but that's for Office² HD, i think you can get Sheet², Doc² and Slide² desperately but i went for all 3 because while i was originally looking for a word processor a spreadsheet processor was an added bonus

Answer (score 2):

### [Pages from Apple](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/id361309726) - $9.99

It has an extremely usable touch based interface. Supports Word import/export, uses iCloud,  ad-free.
 Rich text formatting, images, tables, stores files locally and syncs them when internet is available.

The downsides are lack of Open Document format support and other cloud storages besides iCloud.

### iCloud Word support

export: Go to icloud.com, open Pages, then from the toolbar: <kbd>Tools (wrench)</kbd> > Download a Copy > Word
import: On iCloud.com, open Pages, now drag your Word file to iCloud in the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Microsoft Office](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/office-mobile-for-office-365/id541164041?mt=8) is now available for iPad (with subscription)

It has access to MS OneDrive for cloud storage, and being an actual Microsoft product will likely work well with .doc but not much else.

From the app description

> Sign in with a free Microsoft account to create, edit and save documents for home use. A qualifying Office 365 subscription is required to create, edit and save documents for business use.

So you may or may not need to pay for said subscription, depending on your usage. There are about 5 different subscription types depending on business/education institution size.