# Word processing for iPad with file transfer to/from iPad

Tags: ipad-app, word-processor

While I am aware of my answer [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1574/148) QuickEdit (formally Office² HD) no longer seems to have one of my desired features and the devs have still yet to get back to me as to weather this is a bug or not however there are reviewing noting this feature went missing over a year ago.

That being said I am looking for a word processor for my iPad however my requirements are different.

## Requirements

- **Offline**: i use the program to type up fan fiction and notes when I don't have access to a computer which means I don't have access to the Internet
- **File Transfer**: QuickEdit used to allow me to enable file sharing so can I can transfer files on and off without using iTunes.

  - cloud storage doesn't count because there has been times where my ISP has messed up and I could not communicate to the DNS but I could still use my local network.
  - using iTunes does not count as the PC I use to sync my music library is offline but that means that it can't verify my apps and list them (gives an error about being unable to transfer apps)
  - if an external program is required then it needs to be able to install without the internet, the PC I would install it on is Windows 7 64bit
- **No Sign Up**: I see no need to sign up to something that I am going to be using offline most of the time and the files are stored locally on my iPad
- **Uses .txt files**: I normally just type .txt files, however if it uses another format then it needs to be compatible with Open Office or Notepad++ which is what I use on the PC

## Optional

- **Free**: ideally I would want it to be free but am willing to pay, but I won't pay subscriptions which is what Microsoft is wanting for their Word app
- **Spreadsheets**: one thing that QuickEdit did was also allow spreadsheet editing and at times that has came in handy when I wanted to do auto generated notes (ie making a table which concatenates words from 2 axis) so ideally I would want to be able to keep doing that but if I can't then it's fine